# Partial document read and pagination by property in Marklogic

Tags: graph, pagination, marklogic, marklogic-8, nosql

I'm working on medical system which is using Marklogic. Some time ago I asked a question ([How to query a graph of documents of different types at once in Marklogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550984/how-to-query-a-graph-of-documents-of-different-types-at-once-in-marklogic)) which resulted in our decision to use one large Patient document which holds most of the information for patient. For the purpose of the example I'm presenting a simplified *Patient* document which contains an array of *Appointments*.

**Simplified patient document**

```
{
    "firstName": "Chauncey", 
    "lastName": "Hays", 
    "memberId": "KLKB XMQ 77", 
    "dateOfBirth": "1971-09-11", 
    "gender": "MALE", 


    "appointments": [
        { 
            "name": "Follow Up", 
            "start": "2017-06-08T23:13:00Z", 
            "end": "2017-06-09T00:43:00Z" 
        },
        {
            "name": "Follow Up", 
            "start": "2017-06-09T23:13:00Z", 
            "end": "2017-06-10T00:43:00Z" 
        }
    ]

}
```

One of our use cases is to **return paginated appointments (property of Patient document) filtered by patient data** e.g. find a page of appointments for all MALE patients. We have been struggling with it for a while with no luck. One of the solutions that I see (probably slightly over-engineered) is to return a page of Patients (page of Patients may result in larger number of Appointments than the page size) and filter out appointments on the server side.

My main question is: is it feasible to filter by Patient data (gender=MALE), do partial read (read Appointments) and paginate results by Appointments (property of Patient document) in Marklogic? 
Any comments greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that for your use case structured query option "[searchable-expression](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_43671)" won't work because your query filter is outside  the searchable-expression.  Nevertheless, here's what I tried that matched 0 results:

```
String query = "{ \"search\": {" +
  "\"query\": {" +
  "  \"value-query\": {" +
  "    \"json-property\": \"gender\"," +
  "    \"text\": \"MALE\"" +
  "  }" +
  "}," +
  "\"options\": {" +
  "  \"searchable-expression\": {" +
  "    \"text\": \"appointments\"" +
  "  }" +
  "}}}";
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
RawCombinedQueryDefinition queryDef =
  queryMgr.newRawCombinedQueryDefinitionAs(Format.JSON, query);
queryMgr.search(queryDef, new SearchHandle());
```

And while [extract-document-data](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_44222) works, it's like you described, where you're really paging over docs, not the extracted piece.  Nevertheless, here's what I tried that matched correctly and returned the desired results, but didn't offer a way to paginate as desired:

```
String query = "{ \"search\": {" +
  "\"query\": {" +
  "  \"value-query\": {" +
  "    \"json-property\": \"gender\"," +
  "    \"text\": [\"MALE\"]" +
  "  }" +
  "}," +
  "\"options\": {" +
  "  \"extract-document-data\": {" +
  "    \"extract-path\": \"/appointments\"" +
  "  }" +
  "}}}";
QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
RawCombinedQueryDefinition queryDef =
  queryMgr.newRawCombinedQueryDefinitionAs(Format.JSON, query);
DocumentManager docMgr = client.newDocumentManager();
DocumentPage page = docMgr.search(queryDef, 1);
```

So I think you'll need to resort to a server-side script, ideally in the form of a [resource extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/java/resourceservices#id_49302).  Or you can do an [invoke](http://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/java/resourceservices#id_84134).  Install this script as "/ext/pageAppointments.xqy" in your modules database:

```
  declare variable $start as xs:long external;
  declare variable $pageLength as xs:long external;
  let $appointments :=
    cts:search(collection(), cts:json-property-value-query("gender", "MALE"))/appointments
  return $appointments[$start to ($start + $pageLength - 1)]
```

Then run this in Java:

```
ServerEvaluationCall call = client.newServerEval()
  .modulePath("/ext/pageAppointments.xqy")
  .addVariable("start", 1)
  .addVariable("pageLength", 10);
EvalResultIterator results = call.eval();
try {
  for ( EvalResult result : results ) {
    JsonNode appointment = result.getAs(JsonNode.class);
    System.out.println(appointment);
  }
} finally { results.close(); }
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help!